# Heroku rails app crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash

## i have issue with my app when i deploy it to heroku

**heroku logs**

```
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-07-20T22:54:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-07-20T23:03:33+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET peaceful-reef-1889.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-07-20T23:03:35+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET peaceful-reef-1889.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

https://github.com/Envek/taurus that app itself
on localhost it work perfectly.
Can anyone help me with that error?

Comment: full logs http://pastebin.com/PKMSYM6Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these error lines:

> 2012-07-20T23:39:09+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: Not a git repository (or
>   any of the parent directories): .git

Probably you didn't initialized your repo locally.
Try:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
```

After that deploy to heroku.

Comment: I talk with developer, he said that a problem in old Ruby version — 1.8 and it not work with heroku, because heroku using 1.9 
So in near future, they rewrite all code to 1.9! Be patient

Comment: I don't know what your developer said to you, but I don't think it's ruby version issue. As written in your error messages, it's because you didn't initialized repository with git.